# I have a Java Spring project where Autosys runs on a Unix server. How do I make it work in a Windows environment locally

Tags: windows, bash, shell, autosys

My project is hosted on a Websphere server and my Autosys is implemented in a Unix server where my NAS is located. The autosys jobs invokes Korn Shell scripts in the NAS. I am looking to debug the application locally and would like to have these Autosys jobs running locally on windows. What is the best way to do this?

What I am thinking of is using a CRON scheduler for Eclipse and convert all Korn Shell scripts to Bash scripts. However, this is tedious and I was wondering if there were any easier solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Korn Shell can be run in Cygwin and (I believe) there is autosys support on windows

[Korn-Shell for Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068585/korn-shell-for-windows-7)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Workload_Automation_AE